# Does GCP's Cloud DLP protect data in GCP Cloud Source Repositories also?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp, google-source-repositories

GCP's [DLP API Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/dlp.googleapis.com) has a short description as "Provides methods for detection, risk analysis, and de-identification of privacy-sensitive fragments in text, images, and Google Cloud Platform storage repositories."

I would like to know if GCP Cloud Source Repositories is counted as a Google Cloud Platform storage repositories.

Let me know.

Thanks!

Regards,
Yuva

Answer (score 2):

GCP Cloud Source Repositories are not included in DLP processing.  You can schedule DLP to scan a variety of data resources that are describe at [Inspecting storage and databases for sensitive data](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/inspecting-storage).  But these are:

- Google Cloud Storage (GCS) - Blob storage.
- BigQuery - Petabyte scale data warehouse.
- DataStore - NoSQL database.

The phrase "Google Cloud Platform storage repositories" is a little confusing but what I believe is meant there is "Google Cloud Storage".  Don't let the word "repository" confuse you.  There is no story relating to Cloud Source Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Kolban is correct, however you could scan Cloud Source Repositories using dataflow and inspectContent. Combining dataflow to scan arbitrary data sources using the *content methods is a common solution.